# Javascript Stopwatch not starting at zero

Tags: javascript, onclick, stopwatch

I've got a basic stopwatch here, but the problem is I think it begins counting when the page loads as opposed to when the start button is clicked. Likewise, when you reset and start again the same problem happens.

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer()" />
    <input type="text" id="txt" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop count!" onclick="stopCount()" />
    <input type="button" value="Reset!" onclick="resetCount()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

var start = new Date().getTime(); 
var elapsed = '0.0'; 
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount() {
    var time = new Date().getTime() - start;
    elapsed = Math.floor(time / 100) / 10; 
    if(Math.round(elapsed) == elapsed) { elapsed += '.0'; } 
    document.getElementById('txt').value=elapsed;
    t=setTimeout("timedCount()",50);
}

function doTimer() {
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        timer_is_on=1;
        timedCount();
    }
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on=0;
}

function resetCount() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value='0.0';
    var elapsed = '0.0';
}


</script>
```

I've tried defining the start variable onclick of the start button but not had much success so far. Any help is much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you try including `start = new Date().getTime();` in `doTimer()`?

Comment: I've just tried it, and it makes the stopwatch stop working all together. I can't understand it, what you said seems to make perfect sense but the JS isn't having any of it!

Comment: Please pass functions to setTimeout instead of strings.

Comment: ahh the reason it didn't work when I tried this first time was because I put var start instead of just start. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to include another reset in `doTimer()`:

```
function doTimer() {
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        start = new Date().getTime(); 
        timer_is_on=1;
        timedCount();
    }
}
```

See the running version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aFXax/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is your recording the `start` as soon as the page loads instead of when the user actually clicks on the start button.  To record the start when the user actually clicks on the button change your `doTimer` function to the folowing

```
function doTimer() {
  if (!timer_is_on) {
    start = new Date().getTime();
    timer_is_on=1;
    timedCount();
  }
}
```